# getting error during using command "mvn" in cmd after set the class path for maven

Tags: java, maven

[image]

i am using maven version 3.3.9.

when i am trying to run the command as "mvn"after setting the class path in Enviranment variable getting below shown errors

mvn -versions working fine for me..

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve? a plain mvn command without any goals like clean, package, install would cause this error. Refer Maven documentation for clear details on list of available goals and phases.

Answer (score 0):

If you want maven to help you build (clean, compile, package, install or deploy) your project, you need to specify a goal explicitly.

For example, if you want to compile your project, you use command "mvn compile", and this command will execute all the goals bound to compile phase.

More information:
[Introduction to the Build Lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

Answer (score 0):

Set your gaol before hitting command..

Command should be like 
mvn clean
mvn install and so on